# How to install puppet module from GitHub?

Tags: puppet, installation, github

I've installed [camptocamp/nagios](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/camptocamp/nagios/scores) from Puppet Forge, but seems it has dependencies to [puppet-apache_c2c](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-apache_c2c) which is published on GitHub.

I've installed nagios module as suggested:

```
puppet module install camptocamp-nagios
```

However how do I install missing dependencies?

I've seen some [JIRA ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/BKR-21) which would provide that ability, however it seems it's not implemented yet (status: ready for engineering). So for now is there any workaround? What's the correct approach of installing non-puppet-forge modules?

Comment: Use r10k like everyone else?

Comment: (I don't use r10k... should I?)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a DevOp so I didn't hear about `r10k`. However I'll have a go. Other suggestions/methods are welcomed as well.

Comment: What about `librarian-puppet`, is that suitable as well?

Comment: @kenorb it's suitable but there really is no reason to use it instead of `r10k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't use `r10k` or anything like that.
At the end of the day a puppet module is just a directory in your modules folder.
If you are using git to manage your modules you could add it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), like this:

```
cd modules
git submodule add https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-apache_c2c.git apache_c2c
```

Of course this isn't doing any resolution of dependencies.
You'll have to check the `metadata.json` yourself and install those.
Which is OK for my case, we don't add modules very often.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Which is `cd /etc/puppet/modules; git init; git submodule add ...`.

Answer (score 4):

Using [librarian-puppet](http://librarian-puppet.com/):

```
gem install librarian-puppet
```

Check `modulepath` on Puppet master:

```
puppet config print modulepath --section master
```

Which will give you e.g. `/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules`.

Then create `Puppetfile` one level above path `modulepath`. i.e. `/etc/puppet/environments/production/Puppetfile`:

```
forge 'https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com'

mod 'camptocamp-nagios', :git => 'https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-nagios.git'
```

And run `librarian-puppet install` from the folder where is `Puppetfile` located.

In `.librarian/puppet/config` you can specify custom path for modules installation (relative from `Puppetfile`):

```
LIBRARIAN_PUPPET_PATH: environments/production/modules
```